# Few-to-many modeling in Cassandra or other nosql db

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am learning NoSql, and working with Cassandra.  In my test data set, I have questions, each of which may reference one or more topics (a lightweight quora clone with the relational model shown below).

[image: Approximate relational model]

For example, a question about C++ memory management, might reference the topics, “C++ Programming”, “Software Engineering”, and “Bits and Bytes”.  I need a model that will support query that returns all questions that reference a specific topic.  A naive model might have a table like this:

```
ReferencesTopic: name="<topic>", value=”{questionId[]}”
```

Then a lookup for any topic would return a JSON blob with a list of questionId's for questions that reference that topic.  However, this is a “many-to-few” relationship (perhaps 200 topics, each topic with millions of questionId), and so it seems seems very inefficient.

My thought was to segment the HasTopics for a given topic, perhaps with 1000 questionId's per segment.  This would have two tables:

```
TopicSegments:           name="<topic>", value="{topicSegmentId[]}"
ReferencesTopicSegment:  name=<topicSegmentId>, value="{questionId[]}"
```

This has the benefit of being able to easily query the most recent n questions for a given topic since the most recent topicSegmentId is at the bottom of the list of topicSegmentId.

Is this a reasonable model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Cassandra. You are experiencing the most common challenge when you have experience with relational databases, as it is quite often that this model is tried to applied to Cassandra.

- Cassandra does not have joins or foreign key relationships, as RDBMS.
- The design of the schema should be based on how are you going to do the queries.
- Denormalization is a must, with Cassandra is ok to have duplicated data.

There are multiple resources online to help you understand this new paradigm, for example [rules of data modeling](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling), [DS201 in Datastax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/), for your example with comments handling you should also take a look in this post from [The Last Pickle regarding Time Series](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/08/02/time-series-data-modeling-massive-scale.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I think that one more data (pun intended) point is needed to close this.  With Cassandra, there should be roughly one table per query pattern, and so the ReferencesTopic table that I proposed is a reasonable model for this query.  Partitioning the table at some number of questions will resolve the millions of questions to one topic concern.